# How to measure and log all SQL Server stored procedure execution times manually (don't use SQL Profiler)?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, ado.net

I'm taking the task that building a monitor dashboard for a legacy desktop app (LDA). That LDA was built on .NET Framework 2.0 and using ADO.NET to access the database.

It was installed on the local machine for a lot of departments and internal users. It has a thousand forms, each form has 1-few button that can manipulate the database by calling SQL Server stored procedure.

The issue of LDA is some time, some departments, some users got hang out/slow response when clicking a button. We would like to record all stored procedure execution times and put them all on a monitor dashboard.

We used SQL Server profiler but it is not helpful with us because of not showing which department, which user got a slow response. So we are trying to find a solution by adding tracking code into LDA (as little as possible).

I have an ideal that builds a wrapper class on `SqlCommand` or `SqlConnection` to measure the stored procedure execution time by an extension method like

```
using(var connection = new MyCustomSqlConnection())
{
    ........
    // currentUserObject contains all info of user and department.
    myCustomSqlCommand.ExecutionQuery().TrackingTime(currentUserObject);
    .....
}
```

Is this possible? Do you guys have a sample?

I'm not familiar with the window form. So I so appreciate it if you have any better suggestions based on Form/Button class/event.

Thanks and best regard!

Comment: My opinion on this, don't go building any sort of logging into the front end apps.  You're increasing complexity and potential failure points, your logging may in fact exasperate the very delays your trying to measure.  If you're confident that the delay is in SQL server and not network/environment, you're better off doing your monitoring directly on that

Comment: @Hursey: I intend to build the TrackingTime method as an async calling to an external web service to log SQL command object's statistics. Call and forget. Other logics will be handled in external service. So I think it won't affect LDA so much. I would like to find a solution with minimum cost and risk.